# Soul Point Difference Between Dath Vader and Emperor Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars-the-force-unleashed

In Star Wars The Force Unleashed at the last level is there an soul point difference between Vader and the Emperor?

Comment: "is there an soul point difference" - what doesn that mean? you might want to elaborate/explain :)